# Yii Counting records in model

Tags: php, sql, yii

In my web  application I want to print the no of records  for a particular criteria   . But the output I am getting is  0 , although there are many  records for the matching condition.
This code is inside a view of another model . "$data" belongs to that model

My code  I implemented.

```
$temp=CHtml::encode($data->name);

        $find=ConsumerRequest::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('requested_vegetable'=>$temp));
        $count = count($find);
       echo $count;
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you HTML-encoding something before you feed it to the database? I don't know if that is the problem here, but it's definitely a sign that you are doing something wrong. Also, use `countByAttributes` instead of `findAllByAttributes`.

Comment: tried by removing and just echoing tats not working

Comment: Even countByAttributes does not make any change in the output

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the `findAll()` functions as this pulls over all the data for each row. You can simply use the `count()` or `countByAttributes()` function. I would guess your problem is probably this line:

```
$temp=CHtml::encode($data->name);
```

Most likely you are not storing it in the database HTML encoded. Try just doing this:

```
$count = ConsumerRequest::model()->countByAttributes(array('requested_vegetable'=>$data->name));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `public $count` on your Model right after the **class** syntax. And use CDbCriteria to make a custome query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these methods:

```
$temp=CHtml::encode($data->name);
$count = ConsumerRequest::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"requested_vegetable = '$temp'"));
$count = count($find);
echo $count;
```

OR

```
$temp=CHtml::encode($data->name);
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->condition = "requested_vegetable = '$temp'";
$count = ConsumerRequest::model()->findAll($Criteria);
$count = count($find);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Why would you not bind `$temp` you are directly injecting it into the sql statement. Also with `FindAll()` you are pulling over all the data this is very inefficient, just use `count()`

Comment: I found out the error in the code , it is    only comparing  integer values. not string values.  Is there any way out to compare  string attributes....?

Comment: That should work.Or start using `countByAttributes` as @Pitchinnate said.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this: `$query='SELECT COUNT(id.tbl) FROM tbl';`
CMIIW